# ReactJS: npm package to build basic git GUI?

Tags: git, reactjs, ecmascript-6

This is perhaps an odd question - please don't freak out.

I don't know if I'm mixing too much together but I would like to build a BASIC web GUI that allows users to change content in some files and have the same version control I get from `git`.

(By BASIC I mean `add -A` and `commit -m` and no `reset`, `rebase`, `ammend` etc.)

Here is a rough markup of what I mean:

> data.json

```
{ 
  fieldA: none,
  fieldB: none,
}
```

> FrontEnd.js

```
import { fieldA } from '../data.json'
...
state = {
  fieldA,
  commitMessage: ''
}

handleValue = (fieldA) => {
  this.setState({fieldA})
}

handleMsg = (commitMessage) => {
  this.setState({commitMessage})
}
...
<input type="text" value={this.state.fieldA} onChange={this.handleValue} />

<input type="text" value={this.state.commitMessage} onChange={this.handleMsg} />

<button disable={!fieldA && !commitMessage} onClick={..do magic commit -m} />
```

Is there any package out there that will allow me to do this?

Comment: I understand your problem, and I know it may be frustrating knowing "it's out there, but aargh cant find it", but nevertheless, this is off-topic as you ask us to find a library for you. I suppose yout tried googling, so I'll skip it and I'll just say that Stack Overflow has a policy of trying to keep the question "also usable in future" - libraries/books/etc tend to change, appear, disappear, get obsolete, be better-or-worse for you depending on many things, etc, so we should strive to not ask for them here :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl yes I did Google it first (always do). I don't believe that this question violates the goal and policy of stack overflow. In my normal googling I have come across serval similar type of questions that are still very helpful even though it's a long time since the question was asked. New libraries also get mentioned in older post, so people are keeping it up to date.

Answer (score 1):

For the basic Git operation, you can use [NodeGit](http://www.nodegit.org/)

For the front-end, you have frameworks like [`gitgraphjs`](http://gitgraphjs.com/) (see [used here](http://jsfiddle.net/fracz/guan1oz1/374/))

As an example of a large Javascript Git Front-end, you can have a look at [`FredrikNoren/ungit`](https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit):

[image: https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit/raw/master/screenshot.png]